# SlideToggle content with Navigation?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I want to slidetoggle divs with different content in it by targeting the content by name in my navigation.

I have this already:

```
$(".div1, .div2, .div3").hide();

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("nav a").click(function () {  
    var divname= this.name;
    $("."+divname).siblings().slideUp(500, function () {
    $("."+divname).slideToggle();
});
});
});

<nav>
<a name="div1">SlideToggle Div 1</a>
<a name="div2">SlideToggle Div 2</a>
<a name="div3">SlideToggle Div 2</a>
</nav>

<div id="container">
<div class="div1">Content Div 1</div>
<div class="div2">Content Div 2</div>
<div class="div3">Content Div 3</div>
</div>
```

I want that every div slides up first, then slidesdown with the content of the new div, that is targeted in menue and so forth.

**Problem with that script:**

With two divs it's working. Adding a third does make it slide down and slide up. Adding a forth does make it slide down, slide up and slide down and so forth. Must be something wrong with the siblings idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Whats not working correctly??

Comment: with two divs it's working. adding a third does make it slide down and slide up. adding a forth does make it slide down, slide up and slide down again and so forth. must be something wrong with the siblings idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a working jsfiddle page so look at [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bnf2Y/3/). I did some work on your code check out if this is what you wanted. **UPDATED THE CODE** Retry the link now.

```
$(".div1, .div2, .div3").hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstTime = true;
  $("nav a").click(function() {
    var divname = this.name;
    if (!firstTime) {
        if ($(".slid").hasClass(divname)) {
            firstTime = true;
            $(".slid").removeClass("slid").slideUp();
        } else {

            $(".slid").removeClass('slid').slideUp(500, function() {
                $("." + divname).slideToggle().addClass("slid");

            });
        }
    } else {
        $("." + divname).slideDown().addClass("slid");
        firstTime = false;
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, type error. Thank's. I corrected it. Also added to my question what this script does wrong yet.

Comment: looking into it I understand what you want though.

Comment: @Melros Look at my link that takes you to jsfiddle that shows some jQuery I coded

Comment: Oh, just one additional question: When I click the same link a second time it slides up and down again. Is it possible to just slide up (close) it?

Comment: yes but you didnt say that.. you would have to check if its not the first time to see if the one you are clicking is the one that is already slid adn then change the first time to true again

Comment: Ok, sorry I should have put this within my question. But since I'm still a kind of beginner with jQuery would you like to add it to your answer? That would be so nice! I'm always trying to understand the code by playing around with it afterwards..Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enought for your help! Thank you! :)